# how from Ubuntu to identify disk C, D' etc in windows 10

Tags: gparted, directory

help to understand structure directories in Ubuntu
is there way, simple way to find out which where what disk of Windows - C D etc I see when watch in gparted structure directories in ubuntu 20 04
or may be it is some third party programms that show me from Ubuntu disks in windows 10?

Comment: Disk C, D etc. is a Windows thing. In Linux, you mount the disk in an empty directory. You could mount your NTFS drives inside `/mnt/C`, `/mnt/D` etc. if you like.

Comment: If you put **labels** on your Windows disks, the labels will also be seen by Linux tools, and it will be easy to recognize them. Select labels (names) that are intuitive in order to make it easy to recognize them, for example 'win-sys' and 'win-data'.

Comment: Are C: and D: different sizes?

Comment: please how to "put labels on your Windows disks"?

Answer (score 2):

Linux is more user friendly than Windows. Instead of working with different drives and different file systems, all directories and files in linux are represented within one single directory structure, starting at `/`, root.

Different storage volumes, i.e. different partitions that can reside on the same disk or on a different disk, are mounted on a specific directory within that structure. From then on, all contents on that storage volume are available from within the directory where the storage volume is mounted (connected).

Storage volumes other than the system volume(s) are by default *not* mounted after you start up a system. Removable drives are automatically mounted after you log in. Partitions in fixed drives are only mounted after you click their icon in the file manager. All of these mounts happen, in Ubuntu, in a directory `/media/$USER/<label>`, where `$USER` stands for your login name, and `<label>` is an automatically generated label.

For determining `<label>`, the system will take the volume label of the partition, if one is set. If not, a less recognizable string is used based on the volume identifier.

There, an easy way to recognize your volumes is give them a lable, i.e., set the volume label of the partition. This can be done using the tool "Disks". Highlight the partition, click the cog then select "Edit file system" from the menu. This will display the "Change Filesystem Label" dialog, allowing you to set or change the volume label.

Yes, you can label a disk "DISK_C" if that makes sense to you.